# How to make your virtual assistant speak when there is "google" in your command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a student and I am making a virtual assistant on Python 3.9. I want my assistant answer my questions when I say "google" in command, but I don't know why its not working. I tried so many ways but it still doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it, so I hope you guys can help me to fix it.

Thanks for any help!

**Here is my code:**

```
import speech_recognition 
import pyttsx3

robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
robot_mouth = pyttsx3.init()
voices = robot_mouth.getProperty('voices')
robot_mouth.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def robot_brain(robot_brain):
    print("Jarvis: " + robot_brain)
    robot_mouth.say(robot_brain)
    robot_mouth.runAndWait()

def take_command():
    try:
        with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
            print("Jarvis: I'm Listening")
            audio = robot_ear.listen(mic,timeout=6 )

        print("Jarvis: ...")

        you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio)  
        you = you.lower()
        if "google" in you:
            you = you.replace("google", "")
            print(you)
    except:
        pass
        you = ""
    print("Boss: " + you)  
    return you

def run_google():
    you = take_command()
    print(you)
    if "hello" in you:
        robot_brain = "hello"

    elif "bye" in you:
        robot_brain = "bye"
        print("Jarvis: " + robot_brain)
        robot_mouth.say(robot_brain)
        robot_mouth.runAndWait()

    else:
        robot_brain = "I can't hear you, try again"

while True:
    run_google()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please make sure you have all the necessary modules installed.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes

listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print('listening...')
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
            command = command.lower()
            if 'google' in command:
                command = command.replace('google', '')
                print(command)
    except:
        pass
    return command


def run_google():
    command = take_command()
    print(command)
    if 'play' in command:
        song = command.replace('play', '')
        talk('playing ' + song)
        pywhatkit.playonyt(song)
    elif 'time' in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
        talk('Current time is ' + time)
    elif 'who the heck is' in command:
        person = command.replace('who the heck is', '')
        info = wikipedia.summary(person, 1)
        print(info)
        talk(info)
    elif 'date' in command:
        talk('sorry, I have a headache')
    elif 'are you single' in command:
        talk('I am in a relationship with wifi')
    elif 'joke' in command:
        talk(pyjokes.get_joke())
    else:
        talk('Please say the command again.')


while True:
    run_google()
```